# Call function of class of one assembly from different assembly class

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Phoenix.AccountHolders");
            Type type = assembly.GetType("Phoenix.AccountHolders.AccountHolderAppService");
            object customerAppService = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            MethodInfo getMethod = type.GetMethod("FullName");
            object[] paramss = new object[2];
            paramss[0] = "Farhat";
            paramss[1] = "Ullah";
            string fullName = (string)getMethod.Invoke(customerAppService, paramss);
```

i call FullName function of accountHolderAppService from controller of other assembly.

Following error occured.

Could not load file or assembly 'Phoenix.AccountHolders' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: are you already add reference of the dll to your project ?

Comment: yes i add reference of AccountHolderAppService in AccountHoldersController.